# Idiom/expression that indicates that you can do something conveniently/quickly?

Tags: expressions, idiom-requests

I'm not sure if I'm being clear enough with my question, but there's this expression which goes like "you can do this at the... blank" which means you can do it easily, but I don't remember what it is. Any similar or equivalent expressions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: 'At the double' ?

Comment: "At the drop of a hat" is a common idiomatic expression with the general sense that you seem to have in mind, although it tends to emphasize how quickly something can happen. There are also several idiomatic expressions for indicating that something is easy to do: "easy as pie," "easy as falling off a log," "easy [or _simple_] as abc."